# How to get a union type from a namespace containing multiple types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-typings, union-types

I'm defining types for my `redux` state and corresponding actions.

Here is how I'm organizing it:

```
declare namespace GLOBAL {
  
  interface AUTH {
    user: null | User
    admin: boolean
  }

  interface APP_VERSION {
    CURRENT: number
  }

  interface STATE {
    AUTH: AUTH,
    APP_VERSION: APP_VERSOPM
  }

  declare namespace ACTIONS {    // THESE ARE THE ACTIONS THAT UPDATE THE "GLOBAL" PART OF THE "REDUX_STATE"

     type UPDATE_AUTH = {
       type: "UPDATE_AUTH",
       payload: AUTH
     }

     type UPDATE_APP_VERSION = {
       type: "UPDATE_APP_VERSION",
       payload: APP_VERSION
     }

     // ETC
    
  }

  interface REDUX_STATE {       // THIS IS THE SHAPE OF THE TOP LEVEL REDUX STATE
    GLOBAL: GLOBAL.STATE,       // "GLOBAL" USED WITHIN THE WHOLE APP
    ADMIN: ADMIN.STATE          // "ADMIN" IS ONLY USED IN ADMIN PAGES
  }
  
}
```

I'm stuck now at this point: I need **a way to refer to all those actions that update the `GLOBAL` state.** Something I would use in my `globalStateReducer`, for example:

**Example:**

```
export const globalStateReducer(state: GLOBAL.STATE, actions: XXX) => {};

// NOTE: XXX should translate as the "UNION TYPE OF ALL ACTIONS LISTED IN GLOBAL.ACTIONS"
```

**One possible solution:**

Every time I add an action to `GLOBAL.ACTIONS` I can add it manually to a union type that would be something like this:

```
type ALL_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = UPDATE_AUTH | UPDATE_APP_VERSION | UPDATE_ANOTHER | UPDATE_SOMETHING | ETC...
```

Then I could refer to it in my `globalStateReducer()` (it will also be used in other places):

```
export const globalStateReducer(state: GLOBAL.STATE, actions: GLOBAL.ALL_GLOBAL_ACTIONS) => {};
```

**But that is repetitive work and error prone.**

Is there an automatic way to refer to the union type of all types and interfaces present inside the `GLOBAL.ACTIONS` namespace? Or should I re-defined the shape of my types to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a namespace maybe you could define it as a union from the start.

```
type ACTIONS =
    | {
        type: "UPDATE_AUTH",
        payload: AUTH
    }
    | {
        type: "UPDATE_APP_VERSION",
        payload: APP_VERSION
    }

// Now a helper to access an action type by string key
type ACTION<T, A = ACTIONS> = A extends { type: T } ? A : never

const updateAuth = (): ACTION<'UPDATE_AUTH'> => {
    return ({ type: "UPDATE_AUTH", payload: ... })
}
```

So instead of using `ACTIONS.UPDATE_AUTH` you would use `ACTION<'UPDATE_AUTH'>`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that before. But it makes more difficult to read and I also need the single action types in some places. Like in action creators: `export const updateAuth = (): UPDATE_AUTH => {return ({ type: "UPDATE_AUTH", payload: ...})}`. It's nice that I get auto completion inside the action creator.

Comment: @cbdeveloper The point of the helper at the end is for getting the single action types. Your creator would be `export const updateAuth = (): ACTION<'UPDATE_AUTH'> => {}`

Comment: Yeah, it should work with the `helper` that you've suggested. But I think I'd rather keep adding the types manually in that case. I mean, it does solve the problem I've mentioned, but it creates an extra level of abstraction. I'm sure the `helper` does the job, but it doesn't make it very clear (if I have to debug something 6 months from now). I upvoted your answer, but will try to find another solution to this. Thanks again!